# How to access NancyContext from a route?

Tags: get, nancy

Is it possible to access the NancyContext from a route definition?

What I would like to build is a single route for a legacy request that receives parameters in a way like this:

```
/points/upload?longitude=12.34&latitude=23.45
```

(And I did not find a way to specify these parameters with patterns, as Nancy seems to ignore anything behind the question mark.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Everything after the question-mark is a query-string and you access those using the Request.Query property, inside your route

```
Get["/points/upload"] = x => {
   var long = Request.Query.longitude;
   var lang = Request.Query.latitude;

   return 200;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I was looking for! I couldn't find this in the [documentation](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/Documentation) - did I miss anything?